# Agregar interfaces ui a main window(python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, pyqt5, interfaz-gráfica

```
class MenuA(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        uic.loadUi("Interfaces/MenuAdmi.ui",self)
        self.actionAgregar.triggered.connect(self.AgregarInvent)

    def AgregarInvent(self):
        AgregarInventario.showNormal()

class AgregarInventario(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        uic.loadUi("Interfaces/AgregarInvent.ui",self)

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
MenuA=MenuA()
AgregarInventario= AgregarInventario()
MenuA.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Sin embargo cuando realizo el click del action se muestra el archivo de Agregarinvent.ui en un window aparte.
Como puedo hacer que se muestre esa ventana adentro del main window y no en una ventana aparte?

Comment: Quieres que el QDialog sea parte del QMainWindow? si deseas hacer ello hay 2 posibles soluciones, la primera es añadirlo dentro de QMdiaArea, y esta QMdiArea este dentro del QMainWindow, la segunda solución es cambiar la clase de QDialog a QWidget y colocarlo dentro del QMainWindow mediante un layout

Comment: Cual solucipon deseas?

Comment: Como seria la solucion de "la segunda solución es cambiar la clase de QDialog a QWidget y colocarlo dentro del QMainWindow mediante un layout "? Precisamente eso es lo que busco